# Can't generate data to graph a piecewise function in Python

Tags: python, graph, piecewise

I'm trying to graph this function. x domain is (1,3) a_1 domain is (0,1) and b domain is (0,0.8)
[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyllT.png)
My code is this so far:

```
import numpy as np
def t2(x,a,b):
  if (x <= 1.5 - (a/2)).any():
    imagent2=0
  elif  np.logical_and((1.5) - (a/2) < x, x <=(1.5) + (a/2)).all():
    imagent2=(x-(1.5)+(a/2))/a
  elif  np.logical_and((1.5)+(a/2) < x ,x <= (2.6)-(b/2)).all():
    imagent2=1
  elif  np.logical_and((2.6)-(b/2) < x, x <= 2.6+(b/2)).all():
    imagent2=((2.6)+(b/2)-x)/b
  elif  (((2.6)+(b/2)) < x).any():
    imagent2=0
  return imagent2  
n=5
q = np.linspace(1.01, 2.99,n)
w = np.linspace(0.01,0.99,n)
e = np.linspace(0.01,0.79,n)

X, A, B= np.meshgrid(q, w, e, indexing='ij')

assert np.all(X[:,0,0] == q)
assert np.all(A[0,:,0] == w)
assert np.all(B[0,0,:] == e)

print(t2(X,A,B))
```

I put the .all() and .any() cause i was getting errors without them. I will like to have an array with the values of the function on the specific domain. With that i would graph using f(x) as z, x as x, a as y and b should be represented as a colour. Don't really know how to do that last part also.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What **problem do you encounter** when you try this code? What is your **specific question** about how to proceed? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

In the end i did something like this. Not quite what i wanted but i guess is enough.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

def t2(x,a,b):
     return np.piecewise(x, [np.logical_and(x>1,x<=1.5-(a/2)),np.logical_and((1.5)-(a/2)<x,x<=(1.5)+(a/2)),np.logical_and((1.5)+(a/2)<x,x<=(2.6)-(b/2)),np.logical_and((2.6)-(b/2)<x,x<=2.6+(b/2)),np.logical_and(x<3,((2.6)+(b/2))<x)], [lambda x: 0, lambda x: (x-(1.5)+(a/2))/a,lambda x: 1, lambda x: ((2.6)+(b/2)-x)/b, lambda x: 0])
n=100
x = np.linspace(1.01, 2.99,n)
y = np.linspace(0.01,0.99,n)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
b_vals = [ 0.01,0.4, 0.79 ]
num_subplots = len(b_vals)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
for i,b in enumerate(b_vals):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1 , num_subplots , i+1, projection='3d')
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, np.vectorize(t2)(X,Y,b), cmap=cm.gnuplot)
    ax.set_title('b = %.2f'%b, fontsize=10)
    plt.xlabel("x")
    plt.ylabel("a")
    ax.set_zlabel('T1(x,a,a_2)')
fig.savefig('contours.png', facecolor='grey', edgecolor='none')
```